# Python perform HTTP over one of multiple Ethernet cards

Tags: python, python-2.7, http

My PC has two network cards, one attached to the company intranet and one attached to some test equipment.

How do I exchange HTTP traffic with the test equipment? I need a solution for both Windows and Linux.

Can I just use the  [HTTP protocol client](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) and expect that to sort it out?

Should I use the [socket — Low-level networking interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#module-socket)?

My question is, do I have to somehow indicate that I wish to use a particular network card, or can the o/s somehow figure it out behind the scenes?

Comment: On Windows use `ipconfig` to show you your machine's IP addresses on each of your network cards.  The IP address of the equipment you need to talk to should be enough for the OS to pick the right card.

Comment: @quamrana What happens if both Ethernet cards are using 192.128.xxx.xxx address to communicate to 192.128.xxx.xxx addresses on two different machines? Don't I have to send my HTTP over either `eth0`1 or `eth1`?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have set your network or routing etc. on your machine weirdly it shouldn't be a problem.

for example;
if your test equipment is on the network 192.168.1.0/24 with the ip 192.168.1.2

your computer is set up something like:
interface1 (intranet):
network 192.168.0.0/24
ip 192.168.0.76

interface2 (testnet):
network 192.168.1.0/24
ip 192.168.1.3

then any traffic you direct at 192.168.1.* is going to be sent out through interface2 unless you have manually set the routing to not do so.

Comment: So, the o/s sorts it out for mew? I can just use the HTTP library? On both Windows and Linux?

Comment: What happens if both Ethernet cards are using 192.128.xxx.xxx address to communicate to 192.128.xxx.xxx addresses on two different machines? Don't I have to send my HTTP over either `eth0`1 or `eth1`?

Comment: I would say that would be an unfortunate network configuration since the whole idea of ip-addresses is that for your scope they should be unique. I don't know how httplib would handle that, you could try ip%interface (eg. 192.128.2.2%eth1). When it comes to link-local addresses a few libraries/utilities take that to mean that you want to bind your socket on a specific interface, however, that is a gamble. If you cannot accept not supporting such a configuration it is likely that you are gonna have to write the socket code yourself.

Comment: I was unaware of the possibility of `%interface`. If this will work, it solves my problems. I will read up on it (tomorrow, as I am leaving the office now). Feel free to post an answer based on that - all I want to do is to route to a particular NIC & this looks like the answer.

Comment: mind you, i've only seen it use for link-local addresses where you by necessity need to specify the interface and only a small set of apps/libraries seem to support it for that.

Comment: Ah, pity! Nvm; I am now exploring thew idea of having only one NIC leading to a programmable hub, and let that sort it by traffic type or destination.